# Finding a point on a given line Segment with sum of distance from given points on the line segment is maximum

Tags: math

I need to find the point on given line Segment such the its sum of distance form given points on the line segment is maximum.All given points are lying on the line Segment

Comment: Do you mean *minimum* or *maximum*?  BTW I believe this question is better asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/ .  If you indeed mean maximum, it can be shown that the solution will always be one of the endpoints (sorry, no room for proof in a comment), so all you need to do is check which of the two endpoints has a higher total, and use that.

Comment: Also, if you want the minimum, then just sort the points, and the solution is the "middle one" (median) if there's an odd number of points, or any point inbetween the two "middle ones" if there are an even number of points.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, the point you want will be one of the endpoints. Specifically, it is the endpoint farther from the mean position of the given points.

When the optimum is not between any two of the given points, it's easy to show that the total distance for N given points is just N times the distance from the mean position of the given points. Given that, the optimal point is obviously the endpoint farther from the mean position. Thus, we just need to establish that the optimum cannot lie between any of the given points. Do this inductively.

For a single given point, this is trivially true.

For two given points, consider what would happen if the optimum were to lay between them. The total distance to those points would be just the distance between the points, regardless of where you choose the point. In contrast, choosing the point outside the pair of points would always give a total distance greater than the distance between the two points. Thus, there can't be an optimum between the points; the optimum lies at an endpoint.

Now make the induction step. Assume that the optimum is at an endpoint of a segment with M points. Add two more points, one to the left of all other given points, the other to the right of the given points. If the new optimum isn't between the two new points, it is outside the M+2 points and we are done. If it is between the outermost points, we can consider the shorter segment defined by the outermost points. But this is just a segment with M points, so we know that the optimum is at an endpoint (i.e., at one of the new points) and we have a contradiction.

Put those together, and the optimum is at an endpoint. Determine which one by evaluating the mean position and seeing which endpoint is farther from it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I have totally understood your question, but :

- divide your line segment (AB) in 2 parts in a point C (so that in length AC=CB)
- count the number of points that are placed on each parts

The given point you are looking for is the extremity (so A or B) of the part which contains the less points.

Comment: This doesn't seem to use the distance in any way. Seems like you have a counterexample with three given points, one close to B and two on AC close to C. Or we're reading the problem differently.

Comment: No you're right. It's always an endpoint (extremity) but not the one that contains less points, but the one that does not contain the barycentre.